# Swift Selector with default argument

Tags: swift, unrecognized-selector

I have Write simple Code here

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Cancel, target: self, action: Selector("cancelClick"))
```

Actual Function

```
func cancelClick(isAlert:String = "yes"){
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in

        if isAlert == "yes" {
            Functions.displayAlert("called")
        }
    })
 }
```

1. `self.cancelClick()` - Worked but if i didn't pass the argument
2. `self.cancelClick(isAlert:"no")` - Crashed

So what should be my selector if i have to pass argument in default perameter
tried with both `Selector("cancelClick")` and `Selector("cancelClick:")` but no luck.

Comment: 'Crashed'? With what error?

Comment: @ ABakerSmith unrecognized selector sent "cancelClick"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thing is that the parameter is *not up to you*. It is always the button (the "sender"), and that is the *only* thing it can be.

In other words, if you want this function to have a parameter, then by all means you will need to set your selector string as `"cancelClick:"` - the colon means that it takes a parameter. But that parameter must be the button:

```
func cancelClick(bbi:UIBarButtonItem?) {
```

However, you will notice that I have cleverly made this UIBarButtonItem parameter an Optional. Why do you think I did that? Because now you can *also* call it directly and pass nil:

```
self.cancelClick(nil)
```

Thus, `cancelClick:` now has a way to know whether the call comes from the tapping of a button or by a direct call - if `bbi` is not nil, the button was tapped; if `bbi` *is* nil, we were called directly from code. Sneaky, eh?

Another sneaky approach is to make the parameter an AnyObject:

```
func cancelClick(sender:AnyObject) {
```

The beauty of this is that you can call it with *any* kind of class instance. `cancelClick` can check the type of the `sender`. If it is a UIBarButtonItem (`sender is UIBarButtonItem`), then we were called by tapping the button. Otherwise, if called in code, you can pass in a string or anything else that this function might be prepared to deal with.

Comment: yes mate i got your point thanks i have not thought this from Objective-C purpose as the first argument would the sender so we cannot change that.

Comment: Right, but it isn't "Objective-C" that makes this rule; it is Cocoa. But you have the idea, yes. The target-action _mechanism_ is predetermined; it is part of how Cocoa is built.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Selector("cancelClick:")`, try instead just `"cancelClick:"` with the colon so you can pass an argument.

And as Matt said, the argument you must pass is the `sender` (the button) itself.

Comment: yes but thanks for you help actually i have missed because of default argument