# How to get it working when I send a #selector function call to an objc function which have a default parameter

Tags: swift

Events are calling a #selector function at several places and need different parameter value's. One of the parameters that I f.e use here is a default ( Bool ). But when the setBar function is called the default is always false.

What am I doing wrong?

```
// the to be called function, done by a target action event from a segmentedControl.changeEvent or by a DispatchQueue delay or during a viewDidAppear.

@objc func setBar(segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl, animated: Bool = true) {
    func adjustBar() {
        self.bar!.frame.origin.x = (self.segmentedControl!.frame.width / CGFloat(self.segmentedControl!.numberOfSegments)) * CGFloat(self.segmentedControl!.selectedSegmentIndex)
    }
    if animated == true {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            adjustBar()
        } }
    else {
        adjustBar()
    }
}


// the code that set the target & action for the segmentedControl
segmentedControl!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(setBar), for:UIControl.Event.valueChanged)


// code called when setting the index by code
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(100)) {
        self.setBar(segmentedControl: self.segmentedControl!, animated: false)
    }
```

Everything works except the default value. Any suggestions to fix this?

Thanks you for the answer.
But if I use true like;

```
  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(100)) {
        self.setBar(segmentedControl: self.segmentedControl!, animated: true)
    }
```

then that works. So reading the article mentioned, the signature works

Or if I change/turns things around, to say misuse things, it works.

```
@objc func setBar(segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl, notAnimated : Bool = false) {
    func adjustBar() {
        self.bar!.frame.origin.x = (self.segmentedControl!.frame.width / CGFloat(self.segmentedControl!.numberOfSegments)) * CGFloat(self.segmentedControl!.selectedSegmentIndex)
    }

    print("notAnimated = \(notAnimated)")
    if notAnimated == false {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            adjustBar()
        } }
    else {
        adjustBar()
    }
}
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(100)) {
        self.setBar(segmentedControl: self.segmentedControl!, notAnimated: true)
    }
```

Comment: I believe its not possible to do so, but Im not so sure. Check this out though: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37884522/add-static-parameter-to-selector-in-swift

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30697003/swift-selector-with-default-argument.